# linq to entity framework custom collection class that inherits list(Of T)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

OK, I'm not quite sure how to ask this, but basically I want to create a custom collection class that allows me to have properties on a generic list (Of T) such as:

```
Public ReadOnly Property TotalCalories() As Decimal
        Get
            Dim decTotal As Decimal = 0D
            For Each thisFoodDiaryItem As FoodDiaryItem In Me
                Dim thisNutValue As NutritionalData = (From nd In thisFoodDiaryItem.Food.NutritionalDatas Where nd.NutritionalDefinitionID = 208).FirstOrDefault
                If thisFoodDiaryItem.Food.FoodWeights.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim decWeight As Decimal = thisFoodDiaryItem.Food.FoodWeights(0).WeightInGrams
                    If Not thisNutValue Is Nothing Then
                        Dim decCalories As Decimal = Math.Round((thisNutValue.Value * (decWeight / 100)) * thisFoodDiaryItem.Amount)
                        decTotal += decCalories
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            Return decTotal
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property TotalSugars() As Decimal
        Get
            Dim decTotal As Decimal = 0D
            For Each thisFoodDiaryItem As FoodDiaryItem In Me

                Dim thisNutValue As NutritionalData = (From nd In thisFoodDiaryItem.Food.NutritionalDatas Where nd.NutritionalDefinitionID = 269).FirstOrDefault
                If thisFoodDiaryItem.Food.FoodWeights.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim decWeight As Decimal = thisFoodDiaryItem.Food.FoodWeights(0).WeightInGrams
                    If Not thisNutValue Is Nothing Then
                        Dim decCalories As Decimal = Math.Round((thisNutValue.Value * (decWeight / 100)) * thisFoodDiaryItem.Amount)
                        decTotal += decCalories
                    End If
                End If

            Next
            Return decTotal
        End Get
    End Property
```

I want this class to be used when calling entity framework queries:

```
 Protected Sub BindFoodDiaryItems()
    CurrentFoodDiaryItems = New FoodDiaryItemCollection
    CurrentFoodDiaryItems = (From fdi In db.FoodDiaryItems Where fdi.PersonID = CurrentSiteUser.PersonID And fdi.EntryDate = CurrentDiaryDate).ToList


    If AllMeals Is Nothing Then
        AllMeals = (From m In db.Meals).ToList
    End If

    lvMealsA.DataSource = AllMeals
    lvMealsA.DataBind()

    lblTotalCalories.Text = CurrentFoodDiaryItems.TotalCalories.ToString
    lblTotalSugars.Text = CurrentFoodDiaryItems.TotalSugars.ToString
    lblTotalFats.Text = CurrentFoodDiaryItems.TotalFat.ToString
    lblTotalProtein.Text = CurrentFoodDiaryItems.TotalProtein.ToString
    lblTotalCarbs.Text = CurrentFoodDiaryItems.TotalCarbs.ToString


End Sub
```

I'm assuming it would go something like this:

```
    Partial Public Class FoodDiaryItemCollection
    Inherits List(Of FoodDiaryItem)

    Sub New()
    End Sub

    End Class
```

Error I'm getting:

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NutritionBridgeModel.FoodDiaryItem]' to type 'NutritionBridgeModel.FoodDiaryItemCollection'.**

TIA

Comment: "I want this class to be used when calling entity framework queries:" Could you edit your example to include your desired usage of `CurrentFoodDiaryItems`? Right now, you just create a `FoodDiaryItemCollection` and then you don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

The .Net Framework exposes a lot of awesome extension methods, like Sum, Average, etc...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sweetList = new List<int> { 4, 123, 5, 23, 42 };
        Console.WriteLine("Average: {0}", sweetList.Average());
        Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}", sweetList.Sum());

        var listOfCoolObjects = new List<CoolObject>();
        listOfCoolObjects.Add(new CoolObject { Name = "1434", NeatValue = 42 });
        listOfCoolObjects.Add(new CoolObject { Name = "asdf", NeatValue = 5 });
        listOfCoolObjects.Add(new CoolObject { Name = "fgsdfg", NeatValue = 99 });
        listOfCoolObjects.Add(new CoolObject { Name = "qwerty", NeatValue = 1345 });
        listOfCoolObjects.Add(new CoolObject { Name = "casc", NeatValue = 111 });

        Console.WriteLine("Average: {0}", listOfCoolObjects.Average(x => x.NeatValue));
        Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}", listOfCoolObjects.Sum(x => x.NeatValue));
    }
}

class CoolObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NeatValue { get; set; }
}
```

In your code, you could do something like this:

```
var sum = (From fdi In db.FoodDiaryItems Where fdi.PersonID = CurrentSiteUser.PersonID And fdi.EntryDate = CurrentDiaryDate).Sum(fdi => fdi.SomeValueYouWantToSum)
```

I know you're coding in VB, but I don't know VB at all, so excuse any syntax errors in that last code chunk.

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific with my property needs, they are more complex then just sum, average, etc.  Was just using that as an example.  Check original post for updated needs.